# How to fix gyp ERR! build error using npm?

Tags: reactjs, npm, truffle, unbox

I've been using cmd `truffle unbox react` to create react files in my dapp. However, every time I command it, it pops up `gyp ERR! build error`. I don't know how to fix it. Please help!

I've tried this, still not working.
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/983

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\truffle-react Dapp>truffle unbox react

√ Preparing to download
√ Downloading
√ Cleaning up temporary files
- Setting up boxgyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\truffle-react Dapp\client\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-19T05_46_55_107Z-debug.log
× Setting up box
Error: Command failed: cd client && npm install
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\truffle-react Dapp\client\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-19T05_46_55_107Z-debug.log

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:631:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:668:15)
    at Object.installBoxDependencies (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-box\lib\utils\unbox.js:118:1)
    at Object.setUpBox (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-box\lib\utils\index.js:62:1)
    at Object.unbox (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-box\box.js:58:1)
Truffle v5.0.32 (core: 5.0.32)
Node v12.1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. It was due to a dependency not being compatible with the latest version of Node. I recommend using NVM to temporally roll back the Node version and try again.

Comment: So, which previous version of Node should I use? (for the command of ```truffle unbox react``` )